# Shrink wrap around a letter/text

Tags: cloth-simulation, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to apply a shrink wrap to a letter created using the text tool. The letter is extruded, beveled but still editable. I made it a collision, and yet it does as illustrated in the image below once I run the simulation. Where am I going wrong please? I did also try to solidify the letter - still no luck

[image: Disaster]

Comment: It's better to post blend file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com it is not clear what are you trying to achieve - cloth SIM with negative pressure? Letter probably has to be a mesh object? Or your start cloth shape needs to be adjusted.